# How to overwrite the root properties of a material ui component

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styles

How to overwrite the style properties mentioned on the root element

```
    height: 0.01em;
    display: flex; 
    max-height: 2em;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```
<InputAdornment
 position="end"
>
   {"hello"}
</InputAdornment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding classes to the component

```
<InputAdornment
                          classes={{ root: classes.adornment }}
                          position="end"
                        >
```

```
 adornment: {
      display: "inline-block",
    },
```